# Cannot access secondary GPU error in bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I am having trouble with bumblebee in 14.04. When I run `optirun -vvv glxgears`, this is what I get.

```
[ 3328.473661] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 3328.474046] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 3328.474257] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 3328.474292] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 3328.474310] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 3328.474327] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 3328.474343] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
[ 3328.474358] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 3328.474374] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 3328.474389] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 3328.474404] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[ 3328.474419] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[ 3328.474513] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[ 3355.204485] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initiate mode change.

[ 3355.204505] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initiate mode change.

[ 3355.204509] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 3355.204527] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 3355.204532] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

I've tried reinstalling drivers and bumblebee countless times but I'm running in to the same error.
Running `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` gives
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

and `dmesg|tail` is

```
    [ 4435.416045] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[ 4435.416061] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[ 4435.416205] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[ 4435.416223] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[ 4435.417225] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[ 4440.031094] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[ 4452.040024] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-01c2c8dc-6cb0-27d4-fcb3-34a98594d7e9
[ 4452.040044] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 8, Channel 00000000
[ 4461.054227] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 8, Channel 00000001
[ 4461.054475] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.